# Redis Template does not automatically save a phantom entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

At the risk of making a fool out of myself, I have a question regarding redis that has plagued me for 2 days.
I have a basic project with spring boot 2.4.0 (spring-data-redis included).
I have the following RedisEntity:

```
 @RedisHash
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @ToString
public class RedisEntity implements Serializable {
  private @Id String id;
  private @Indexed String secondaryIndex;
  private @TimeToLive Long expirationTime;
```

And a basic service that saves my redis entity:

```
 public String persistEntity() {
    RedisEntity myEntity = new RedisEntity();
    myEntity.setId("1234");
    myEntity.setExpirationTime(10L);
    myEntity.setSecondaryIndex("456");

    cacheTemplate.opsForValue().set(myEntity.getId(), myEntity,
        myEntity.getExpirationTime(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      
    log.info("Saved entity to REDIS! Entity=" + myEntity);
    return myEntity.toString();
  }
```

The redis template configuration is the following:

```
@Bean
  public RedisTemplate redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory rcf) {
    return createTemplate(rcf, new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(RedisEntity.class));

  }

  private <K, V, S extends RedisSerializer> RedisTemplate<K, V> createTemplate(
      RedisConnectionFactory factory, S valueSerializer) {
    RedisTemplate<K, V> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(factory);
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(valueSerializer);
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
    return redisTemplate;
  }
```

The entity is saved in redis, but when it expires, I cannot retrieve the value ( the phantom entity is not present)
I have put the `@EnableRedisRepositories(shadowCopy = ShadowCopy.ON)` on my main class but to no avail.
When the entity expires, redis deletes everything.

Has someone experienced something similar? Do I need to manually save a copy and put its expiration time at 5 minutes?

Comment: Once a key is expired means you won't find the same key in Redis. What's the deal here?

Comment: @sonus21 I was talking about the phantom key

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I had to set the property enableKeyspaceEvents in @EnableRedisRepositories annotation.

`enableKeyspaceEvents = RedisKeyValueAdapter.EnableKeyspaceEvents.ON_STARTUP`

I got the idea after reading the documentation for [Spring Data Redis (Time To Live section)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.7.2/reference/html/#redis.repositories.expirations)

> By default, the key expiry listener is disabled when initializing the application. The startup mode can be adjusted in @EnableRedisRepositories or RedisKeyValueAdapter to start the listener with the application or upon the first insert of an entity with a TTL. See EnableKeyspaceEvents for possible values.

I hope this helps.